# PHPUnit: how do I mock multiple method calls with multiple arguments?

Tags: php, mocking, tdd, phpunit

I am writing a unit test for a method using PHPUnit. The method I am testing makes a call to the same method on the same object 3 times but with different sets of arguments. My question is similar to the questions asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484602/mock-in-phpunit-multiple-configuration-of-the-same-method-with-different-argum) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988616/phpunit-mock-method-multiple-calls-with-different-arguments)

The questions asked in the other posts have to do with mocking methods that only take one argument.

However, my method takes multiple arguments and I need something like this:

```
$mock->expects($this->exactly(3))
->method('MyMockedMethod')
    ->with(
        $this->logicalOr(
            $this->equalTo($arg1, $arg2, arg3....argNb),
            $this->equalTo($arg1b, $arg2b, arg3b....argNb),
            $this->equalTo($arg1c, $arg2c, arg3c....argNc)
        )
    );
```

This code doesn't work because `equalTo()` validates only one argument. Giving it more than one argument throws an exception:

> Argument #2 of PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_IsEqual::__construct() must be a numeric

Is there a way to do a `logicalOr` mocking for a method with more than one argument?

Comment: You have not formulated a question (with real words). Also you have not explained why the code you added specifically does not work for you. That might sound redundant, but that information will help to make your question more clear and easier to provide an answer. We can not look into your brain.

Comment: @Thomas: I came here to ask this *exact* question, so I updated and upvoted yours, I hope you don't mind. (And now we play the waiting game...)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

In my case the answer turned out to be quite simple:

```
$this->expects($this->at(0))
    ->method('write')
    ->with(/* first set of params */);

$this->expects($this->at(1))
    ->method('write')
    ->with(/* second set of params */);
```

The key is to use `$this->at(n)`, with `n` being the Nth call of the method. I couldn't do anything with any of the `logicalOr()` variants I tried.

Comment: I think the key here is that `with` takes a series of constraints (implying an `equalTo` if just a value is given). You *should* be able to use `logicalOr`, but only in the context of each argument separately (which might not be very useful).

Comment: @JohnFlatness: You are right, I *should*! :) I am surprised by the fact that something so basic is limited to one argument.

Comment: @drHannibalLecter This works, but the problem here is that it hard codes your test to care about the internal implementation of the test case.

Comment: @drHannibalLecter   I will probably mark this as the answer, but I would like to wait and see of there is anyone has a solution with the logicalor implementation.

Comment: @Thomas: I agree that it's bad, but unless PHPUnit guys do something about it, I think we're stuck with it.. :-\

Comment: @drHannibalLecter It seems the index starts at "1" and not "0".

Comment: @GeoffreyBrier: my usage as tested right now shows that the index begins at 0.

Comment: Just a note here: The index for `$this->at()` starts with zero, but increases by _every_ method-call on the mocked object. @GeoffreyBrier, that may've been the reason why it, for you, was the index 1 .... Read here for more info: http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects.tables.matchers

Comment: Thank you @SimonSimCity!! Didn't think it'd be EVERY method call, this is so unstable :(

Comment: quick note at matcher is deprecated and will be removed in phpunit 10, cody's answer should be used instead, including withConsecutive

Comment: @RishirajPurohit We cannot use cody's answer as InvocationMocker::withConsecutive() is deprecated in PHPUnit 9.6 and removed from PHPUnit 10.

Answer (score 71):

For others who are looking to both match input parameters and provide return values for multiple calls.. this works for me:

```
    $mock->method('myMockedMethod')
         ->withConsecutive([$argA1, $argA2], [$argB1, $argB2], [$argC1, $argC2])
         ->willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls($retValue1, $retValue2, $retValue3);
```

Answer (score 34):

[Stubbing a method call to return the value from a map](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#test-doubles.stubs.examples.StubTest5.php)

```
$map = array(
    array('arg1_1', 'arg2_1', 'arg3_1', 'return_1'),
    array('arg1_2', 'arg2_2', 'arg3_2', 'return_2'),
    array('arg1_3', 'arg2_3', 'arg3_3', 'return_3'),
);
$mock->expects($this->exactly(3))
    ->method('MyMockedMethod')
    ->will($this->returnValueMap($map));
```

Or you can use

```
$mock->expects($this->exactly(3))
    ->method('MyMockedMethod')
    ->will($this->onConsecutiveCalls('return_1', 'return_2', 'return_3'));
```

if you don't need to specify input arguments

Comment: You misunderstood the question, it's not about the return values, it's about different arguments for multiple calls of the method.

Comment: @drHannibalLecter OK, got it. Just confused `with()`/`will()`

Comment: onconsecutive calls is so much better then manually doing at()

Comment: onConsecutiveCalls was the answer for me just now. Worked awesome; thank you!

Answer (score 15):

In case someone finds this without looking at the [correspondent section](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects) in the phpunit documentation, you can use the **withConsecutive** method

```
$mock->expects($this->exactly(3))
     ->method('MyMockedMethod')
     ->withConsecutive(
         [$arg1, $arg2, $arg3....$argNb],
         [arg1b, $arg2b, $arg3b....$argNb],
         [$arg1c, $arg2c, $arg3c....$argNc]
         ...
     );
```

The only downside of this being that the code MUST call the **MyMockedMethod** in the order of arguments supplied. I have not yet found a way around this.

Comment: I believe this is what the "map" functions are for e.g. willReturnMap or returnValueMap - like a lookup from params to returns.